# using orElseGet vs orElse in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a service that return a OptionalDouble, if it is null i return a value from another service, but I don't know if it is better orElseGet or orElse in terms of performance or best practices..

Option1)

```
fixerService.getRate(addWalletAmount.getMenuSymbol())
                                    .orElseGet(() -> menuService
                                                    .findBySymbol(addWalletAmount
                                                            .getMenuSymbol())   
                                                            .getPrice()
                                                            .doubleValue());
```

Option2)

```
 fixerService.getRate(addWalletAmount.getMenuSymbol())
                                    .orElse(menuService
                                                    .findBySymbol(addWalletAmount
                                                            .getMenuSymbol())   
                                                            .getPrice()
                                                            .doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course `orElseGet()` is preferable. `orElse()` would execute your service even when the `OptionalDouble` is not empty, which is wasteful (since `menuService.findBySymbol(addWalletAmount.getMenuSymbol()).getPrice().doubleValue()` is the argument passed to the `orElse()` method, and it must be evaluated before `orElse()` is executed).

`orElseGet()` would only execute your service if the `OptionalDouble` is empty.